# Call an Activity from a service class when they belong to diffrent modules

Tags: android, service, module

I have  two modules app and library. I have MusicMainActivity class in app module and Notification service  class in library module.Now I want to call MusicMainActivity from a service class. I tried this by  using

```
   Intent in-new Intent(this,packagename.MusicMainActivity.class);
```

and also

```
  Intent in-new Intent(this,MusicMainActivity.class);
```

But  this   show an  error on   MusicMainactivity.

Error:(326, 48) error: cannot find symbol class MusicMainActivity
Error:Execution failed for task ':library:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

library module gradle file
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

```
   android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "armeabi", "mips"
    }

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
   }
 }

  dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile files('libs/aacdecoder-android-0.8.jar')
 }
```

app moudle  gradle file

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

   android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.adio"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

}
   buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),         'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
   }
  }

    repositories {
      flatDir {
    dirs 'libs'
   }
  }

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile project(':library')
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'

  }
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: What is the error? Is it a compiler error or a run-time error?

Comment: The MainMusicActivity  shows the  error As this is not present in library module where the service class exists

Comment: Please edit your question with the exact error message, word for word.

Comment: I already edit dis see above

Comment: What is the error message? You should click on the Build button on the toolbar. Then you can see the exact reason for the error. If you don't understand what it means, please copy and paste it here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the app module as a dependency to the library module. You can do this by manually editing the build.gradle file of the library module, adding the line

```
compile project(':app')
```

Or you can use the Module Settings dialog in Android Studio.

Alternatively, you can configure an intent filter which would allow you to start your activity without explicitly using its class name in the library module. See [Intents and Intent Filters](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) for more details. This choice is actually preferable because it is much more flexible.

Comment: compile project(':app')  will generate circular  depedency app>library>app  and  the  second  solution also not work

Comment: @SatwinderjitSingh If you want help, you need to give us more information than "it's not working". Feel free to post a new question.

Comment: @SatwinderjitSingh You code move the activity to the library. That should solve all the problems.

Comment: but it will cause other problems if  I move activity to library

Comment: Hey can I contact you via ur email-id

Comment: @SatwinderjitSingh what other problems?

Comment: I have  use  the  toolbar in  activity  which shows  the  error  and  also the   accessbility  of  one  activity  to other  also result in error

Comment: @SatwinderjitSingh you need to edit your question to provide more specific details. Or better yet post a new question.